# What is the soln to the differential equation : $x'''+x''+xx' = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x'''+x''+xx' = 0, \quad x' = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$
Is there an analytic soln for this?
I am very new to numerical methods also, how do I solve this in python, if a numerical method is the only possibility?

Comment: The Physics SE site might be a better fit for this.

Comment: Are you sure this equation correctly reflects the physical system? Is $x$ scalar or a vector? Is the product a simple product or a cross product?

Comment: Yes, this is a correct representation of the physical system. x is the position of the particle at time t, it is a vector. The multiplication is a simple product.

Comment: The first integral takes you to $x''+x'+\frac 12x^2=C$.  If $x$ is small you can expand in a power series.  I can't go further and neither can [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%2Bx%27%2Bx%5E2%2F2%3D0)

Comment: Does analytic mean expressible as a power series?

Comment: Not necessarily. Here, I just mean analytic solution as one that does not involve any numerical methods.

Comment: @TheCount Unfortunately it isn't.  Stuff like differential equations are purely mathematical questions, so the OP was correct to ask it here on SE.Math if they were asking about an analytical approach.  SE.ComputationalScience would tend to be better for numeric approaches.

Comment: If $x$ is a vector and the multiplication $xx'$ a simple product, resulting in a scalar, then what is the definition of the addition of vector and scalar?

Comment: @LutzL Take x as a scalar. I have taken care of directions prior to arriving at this diff EQ. So it's safe to consider x as a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d^3x}{dt^3}+\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+x\frac{dx}{dt}=0 \tag 1$$
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{x^2}{2}=c_1$$
This is an ODE of autonomous kind. The usual way to solve it is the change of function :
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=y(x)\quad;\quad \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=y\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$y\frac{dy}{dx}+y+\frac{x^2}{2}=c_1\tag 2$$
This is an Abel's differential equation. Most of them are not analytically solvable in form of a finite number of standard functions. See https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf

I didn't check if this Abel's ODE belongs or not to the solvables ones. Even if the answer was yes, this would be much more complicated than numerical solving.

In practice using a numerical method of solving is recommended. Especially in the present case with a first order non-linear ODE $(2)$ which is simpler than the original third order non-linear ODE $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

So, given the *ordinary differential equation*:
$$\dddot{x}(t) = - \ddot{x}(t) - x(t) \cdot \dot{x}(t)\,, $$
we can solve it numerically by applying, for example, the **method of Runge-Kutta-4**.

To do this, first of all, we must assume a reasonable number of *initial conditions*, for example:
$$x(0) = 1\,, \; \; \; \; \; \; \dot{x}(0) = 3\,, \; \; \; \; \; \; \ddot{x}(0) = 2\,,$$
then write this third-order differential equation in an *equivalent system of three differential equations of the first order*, naturally with the respective *initial conditions*:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t) = y(t) \\
\dot{y}(t) = z(t) \\
\dot{z}(t) = - z(t) - x(t) \cdot y(t) \\
x(0) = 1 \\
y(0) = 3 \\
z(0) = 2 
\end{cases} \;.
$$
At this point it's necessary to choose the spreadsheet where to implement the aforementioned numerical method, I trivially choose *Microsoft Excel*. In particular, I set the sheet as follows:

[image]

where I highlighted in light red the initial conditions and in light green the step with which to discretize the integration interval, assumed in the following equal to $0 \le t \le 2.50\,s$.

Now it's time to fill in the first row of the table as follows:

[image]

therefore it is time to compile also the second line, starting from the first block:

[image]

We're done writing. All that remains is to complete the compilation of the second line by dragging down the first, then highlight the second complete line by dragging until $t = 2.50\,s$, obtaining:

[image]

*Dulcis in fundo*, it's sufficient to place on the abscissas $t$ and on the ordinates $x(t)$, obtaining:

[image]

All this to show that it isn't necessary to have a sophisticated software to solve numerically an ordinary differential equation, even if, for example, writing in *Wolfram Mathematica*:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'''[t] == -x''[t] - x[t] x'[t], 
               x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 3, x''[0] == 2}, 
               x[t], {t, 0, 2.5}];

Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], 
     {t, 0, 2.5}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

you get immediately:

[image]

but perhaps, especially at the beginning, it is better to get your hands dirty in Excel to put the theory into practice, which must be studied in depth!

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. It really helped me.